# performance issues with finding nth occurence of a character with a regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regex to find the `nth` occurrence of a character in a string, here's the code:

```
 public static int NthIndexOf(this string target, string value, int n)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(target, "((" + value + ").*?){" + n + "}");

        if (m.Success)
        {
            return m.Groups[2].Captures[n - 1].Index;
        }
        else
        {
             return -1;
        }
    }
```

Now, I have 1594 entries in this string, with 1593 semicolons. If I write:

```
tempstring.NthIndexOf(";", 1593)
```

The answer comes back immediately and correctly. If I give it anything over 1594 it hangs. Does anyone know how to fix this?

#### Test Case

```
 string holder = "test;test2;test3";
        string test = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
        {
            test += holder;
        }
        int index = test.NthIndexOf(";", 2000);
```

This takes a very long time. Change 600 to 6 and it is very fast. Make 2000 to 1700 and it is very fast as well.

Why is my regular expression so slow?

Comment: Hangs?  Like the call to .Match never returns?

Comment: I've let it run for a minute with no return. The call with 1593 takes place in milliseconds

Comment: An indication what you are *actually* trying to do would be helpful. Maybe you are approaching this from the wrong side.

Comment: I want to find the position of the nth occurrence of a character. I then split it with the string.substring and string.remove functions based on that index.

Comment: Why don't you loop through the characters in the string and keep a count of how many times you've seen ';'?

Comment: I am all about work-arounds, but I'm curious to see what's wrong.  Can you repro the problem with a more simple inputs?

Comment: for small strings (20 semicolon delimited strings) it returns -1 quickly. For 1800, it takes a very, very long time

Comment: Oh, because it is capturing each instance.  Yeah, I can see how that would slow quickly as your input string increases in size (Capture list grows indefinitely).  You should probably use a less stateful approach.

Comment: right, but if I choose the anything less than 1+actual count it is very, very fast

Comment: @Steve: Your regex generates an *excessive* amount of backtracking upon a non-match. That's why it stalls on long strings and high n. Gumbo's Version fails a bit faster, but still Daniel L's one-pass for loop will be considerably faster than a regex approach.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, could you explain why? I'm still learning regex

Comment: You are seeing the effect of this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: What, you've read that whole thing in *four minutes*? :-)

Comment: more of a perusal :D. I do read very fast however...

Comment: Note that all of your "Change X to Y and it becomes very fast" are essentially "Change it so that a match can be found and it becomes very fast"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're really only looking for character repetitions, and not string repetitions, then you should be able to replace you method with something simple like

```
public static int NthIndexOf(this string target, char testChar, int n)
{
   int count = 0;

   for(int i=0; i<target.Length; i++)
   {
      if(target[i] == testChar)
      {
         count++;
         if(count == n) return i;  
      }
   }

   return -1;
}
```

and use that.  It should have far fewer limitations.

As for why your original regex is going slow, here's what I suspect:

- For your fast case, it's working because it can find a match on it's first pass through (with each group matching exactly one character)
- For the slow case is because it can't find a match (and won't ever find one, because there aren't enough semicolons to satisfy the regex), but it  recursively tries every possible way to break up the string (which is a really big operation)

Comment: +1 - don't ever use regex when you're doing simple string operations. Use builtin functions. This one might be even faster if it used something like (I guess .net has some internal .indexof):

while (n-- > 0) { index = target.IndexOf(textChar, index+1)); if (index==-1) return -1; }
return index;

Comment: I expect internal optimizations here... Sure enough, Reflector reveals: public extern int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count);

Comment: well, initially this was meant to be more general purpose. I do agree with you however.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a more distinct and efficient regular expression:

```
"^(?:[^" + value + "]*" + value + "){" + (n - 1) + "}([^" + value + "]*)
```

This will build the following regular expression for `tempstring.NthIndexOf(";", 1593)`:

```
^(?:[^;]*;){1592}([^;]*)
```

But this will only work for single characters as separator.

Another approach would be to step through each character and count the occurences of the character you were looking for.

Comment: +1 for providing a faster regex. Does .NET regex support atomic grouping (?>...)? This could help improve performance. I'm not sure if possessive quantifiers ({1592}+) are supported, but they would speed up the process as well.